# pagedList loading all items at once

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I've trying to integrate the architecture components in my app, viz Pagination, LiveData, ViewModel.
Room is already integrated and tested before so I can return a `DataSource.Factory<Integer, DbEntity>` from my DAO class. This is my code for creating LiveData of PagedList:

```
 PagedList.Config pagedListConfig =
            (new PagedList.Config.Builder()).setEnablePlaceholders(true)
                .setPrefetchDistance(5)
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                .build();

        LiveData<PagedList<DbEntity>> dbEntities = new 
LivePagedListBuilder<>(DAO.getItemList(timeNow), pagedListConfig).build();
```

And I am observing on this livedata in my fragment class:

```
viewModel.dbEntities.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<DbEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<DbEntity> inboxEntities) {
                adapter.submitList(inboxEntities);
            }
        });
```

The problem is the list is taking too long to draw and it seems that all the items in the list (1300) are being drawn on the first go.

I verified this at two places : `onChanged` is called with the PagedList size equal to 1300 and `onBindViewHolder` of adapter is being called for all the positions upto 1300.

Am I doing sth wrong here?

Comment: Is RecyclerView nested? (PagedList.size() *returns size of the list, **including any not-yet-loaded null padding***)

Comment: yes, recycler view is inside linear layout. how does it matter?

Comment: because nesting scrollable view makes no sens ... especially if you set wrap_content as child height ... just think about it for a while ... it means take as much place as children takes ... which means bind all children at once ... which means no view recycling

Comment: got it. Btw, it's returning correct no of elements after disabling placeholders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working. It's returning correct no of elements after disabling placeholders

Comment: Hey, I'm having the exact same issue, but my RV isn’t nested or something, I'm just using Fragments with FrameLayout as parent. What do you mean by "disabling placeholders"?